# How can I get the VMware view agent version of VMs with powercli?

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter, vdi, powercli

How can I get the VMware View Agent version running on a VM with powercli or View Powercli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `vdmadmin.exe` which is available on your connection server in \Program Files\VMware\VMware View\Server\bin.

```
vdmadmin -d <pool> -getversion

D:\Program Files\VMware\VMware View\Server\bin> vdmadmin -A -d pc10 -getversion
Agent Versions
Pool: pc10 Machine: pc1018 Version: 5.2.0 Install: 5.2.0 build-987719 Build: 17180
Pool: pc10 Machine: pc1010 Version: 5.2.0 Install: 5.2.0 build-987719 Build: 17180
Pool: pc10 Machine: pc1011 Version: 5.2.0 Install: 5.2.0 build-987719 Build: 17180
Pool: pc10 Machine: pc1012 Version: 5.2.0 Install: 5.2.0 build-987719 Build: 17180
```

Wrote a small Powershell script to make this easier [here](http://colelavallee.com/2016/04/02/getting-vmware-view-agent-version/).

Comment: Really? I find it hard to believe the vmware.view.Broker snapin can't grab that info. Is there really no way to get this with the cmdlets?

Comment: This has a list of what's available via [PowerCLI and vdadmin](https://pubs.vmware.com/view-52/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.view.integration.doc%2Fview_integration_powershell.5.4.html)